# How to use Facebook Web Hosting for my Unity Game for both WebGL and GameRoom

Tags: unity, webgl, facebook, unity-webgl

As can be seen from the 
[Facebook's official Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gameroom/requirements#add)

It says that

> To have both a Gameroom and a Facebook Web Game, you should leave your Facebook Web Games URL (https) unchanged. For example, https://friendsmashsample.herokuapp.com/

and also

> Otherwise, if you only have a Gameroom title, you should enter https://localhost/ as shown here:

I wanted to know if there is a way to get both of them working instead of hosting WebGL game on my server and putting it's URL?

I have even tried to enable the Simple Web Hosting but the toggle just reverts Back to off upon saving.

[image: Image showing the toggle that turns off upon saving!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now fixed. 
Seems like the recent issue with Facebook various API deprecation and changes of terms and condition caused this.